# Can I add a key prop to a React fragment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am generating a `dl` in React:

```js
<dl>
  {
    highlights.map(highlight => {
      const count = text.split(highlight).length - 1;

      return (
        <>
          <dt key={`dt-${highlight.id}`}>{highlight}</dt>
          <dd key={`dd-${highlight.id}`}>{count}</dd>
        </>
      );
    })
  }
</dl>
```

This gives me the warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

This will remove the warning, but doesn't generate the HTML I want:

```js
<dl>
  {
    highlights.map(highlight => {
      const count = text.split(highlight).length - 1;

      return (
        <div key={highlight.id}>
          <dt>{highlight}</dt>
          <dd>{count}</dd>
        </div>
      );
    })
  }
</dl>
```

And I cannot add a `key` prop to a fragment (`<>   </>`).

How can work around this?

---

I am using React `16.12.0`.

Comment: `<React.Fragment key={'foo'}>`. Don't use the shortcut syntax. See [keyed fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-fragment.html)

Comment: Just a suggestion, don't use index as key. See here why: [react using index as key for items in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59517962/react-using-index-as-key-for-items-in-the-list)

Answer (score 504, accepted):

To add a key to a fragment you need to use full Fragment syntax:

```
<React.Fragment key={your key}>
...
</React.Fragment>
```

See docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments

Answer (score 40):

Yes, you can add a key in the below form Fragment which is not possible in the shorter version of Fragments(i.e, <></>)

```
<Fragment key={your key}></Fragment>
```

[For Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this way to auto assign key to your component list

`React.Children.toArray(someData.map(data=><div>{data.name}</div>))`

Comment: I don't understand this solution.... what happens to the children on a re-render? How does React know which div corresponds to which array element without a key?

Comment: React automatically adds a unique key to each element in a list.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass key to a Fragment, you can’t use the <>...</> syntax. You have to explicitly import Fragment from 'react'

```
<Fragment key={yourKey}>
 ....
</Fragment>
```