# "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop" error in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning getStaticProps in NextJS. I am making use of the https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts API to render posts on a page. Following is my code for the JS file:

```
function PostList({posts}){
    return (
        <>
        <h1>
            List of posts
        </h1>
        {
            posts.map(post => {
                return (
                <>
                    <div key={post.id}>
                        <h2>{post.id} {post.title}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                </>    
                    
                )
            })
        }
        </>
        )

}

export async function getStaticProps(){
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    const data = await response.json()
    return {
        props: {
            posts: data
        }
    }
}

export default PostList
```

However, the console gives me the following error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4045 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I am assigning the ID of each post as the key in the "div" tag. Yet, I am still getting the error. Is there something wrong with my code or is there something else I am supposed to be adding?

Comment: Change `<>...</>` inside your `map` to `<Fragment key={post.id}>...</Fragment>` (and remove that key from `div`). (Add `import { Fragment } from 'react';`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add a key prop to a React fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390955/can-i-add-a-key-prop-to-a-react-fragment)

Comment: @brc-dd Your answer fixed the error. Any particular reason why assigning the ID in the div tag was causing the problem?

Comment: @mukunda `div` is not a (direct) child of the array. `<>...</>` is. `<>` is a shortcut of writing `React.Fragment`. Read the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of <></> use the below form of Fragment which allows to set the key.

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>... </React.Fragment>
```

[For Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add a `key` attribute to the tag surrounding dom node inside the map.

```js
function PostList({posts}){
    return (
        <>
        <h1>
            List of posts
        </h1>
        {
            posts.map(post => {
                return (
                    <div key={post.id}>
                        <h2>{post.id} {post.title}</h2>
                    <hr/>
                    </div>  
                )
            })
        }
        </div>
        )

}
```