# This React-Native warning has refused to go: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an app with `React Native` and I've used the `map` method to show two items in an array.
But the warning keeps showing:

> ```
> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
> ```

Here is my code:

```
<View>
  {arrayType.map((item, key)=> {
    return(
      <>
        <View key={item + key} style={customStyle.main}>
          <Text>{item}</Text>
        </View>
      </>
    )
  })}
</View>
```

Why is it still showing that warning?

Comment: We don't know since we have no clue whats in `arrayType`

Comment: Might be that the Fragment need an unique key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add a key prop to a React fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390955/can-i-add-a-key-prop-to-a-react-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `React.Fragment`: `<></>`.

try this instead:

```js
<View>
  {arrayType.map((item, key)=> {
    return(
      <View key={item + key} style={customStyle.main}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  })}
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved it by removing the react.fragment.

Answer (score 1):

**The parent component should consist key prop when rendering list in loop**.

so code should look like this.

```
<View>
   {arrayType.map((item, key) => {
      return(
         <View key={item + key} style={customStyle.main}>
            <Text>
               {item}
            </Text>
         </View>
      )})
   }
</View>
```